# How scrub code cell contents from a jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jinja2, jupyter-lab, nbconvert

I am working on a series of jupyter notebooks for teaching purposes. I want to give these notebooks to the students, however, first I want to erase the contents of the code cells (but not delete the cells themselves!). The whole point is that the students go through the notebook and fill in the cells.

For example, here is what I create:

[image: teacher version]

And here is what I want to export for the students:

[image: student version]

There are a lot of notebooks so I would like to automate this task. I tried playing around with `jupyter nbconvert` but the default options (like `--no-input`) don't seem to do what I want. Do I really have to dive into the world of jinja templates, or is there an easier way?

Comment: The notebooks are just JSON files so you could create a custom script in the language of choice (Python I guess) which replaces content of the code cells with an empty line. If you get stuck please add any relevant details here and tag me in a comment.

Comment: @krassowski in the end this is what I did, but I found it rather unsatisfying and would have expected nbconvert to be easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a common use case you have, usually people want to remove the output of a cell. But you can write code similar to the [ClearOutputPreprocessor](https://github.com/jupyter/nbconvert/blob/main/nbconvert/preprocessors/clearoutput.py#L19):

```py
def clear_inputs(notebook_file):
    with open(notebook_file) as fp:
        raw_notebook = nbformat.read(fp, as_version=4)

    for cell in raw_notebook.get("cells"):
        if cell.cell_type == "code":
            cell.source = []

    with open(notebook_file, "w") as fp:
        nbformat.write(raw_notebook, fp)
```